# How can I upload my game file to my Github account and allow people to run it on their browser?

Tags: github, publish

I have made this board game which can be run on browser, and I would like to upload this file to github and allow people to run it on their browser by just typing the URL for existing file on Github.

I eventually want it to have like [this](http://starmelt.github.com/craftyjstut/samegame/4_polishing/).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've had so much fun with that game :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That game is published on [GitHub Pages](http://pages.github.com/). To make one for your project, simply follow their [handy guide](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-pages-with-the-automatic-generator).

To see how it's done for the `craftyjstut` project, take a look at the [`gh-pages` branch on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/starmelt/craftyjstut/tree/gh-pages).